# Fully Custom UI For Twitter Digits Sign-in Flow

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, twitter-digits

I understand that you can customize the appearance of the Twitter Digits sign-in flow (as specified [here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/digits-theming)). Is there a way however to use a fully custom UI for this flow, while using the Digits authentication services?

I know that you can use a custom button to kick off the authentication flow, but everything from that points onwards till the `DGTSession` object successfully returns after authentication appears to be handled by the native UI of the Digits feature. Can we use a custom screen flow here?

[image]

Comment: It appears that according to Twitter dev support, this might not be possible right now. Is there any other similar framework or service which offers this functionality of signing-in with your phone number?